# Making primary key out of 2 foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How do I make a composite primary key out of 2 foreign keys like this?

[image]

When I do this in my Account:

```
@Entity
public class Account {
@Id
private int id;
private String number;
private String IBAN;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Payment> getPayments() {
    return payments;
}

public void setPayments(List<Payment> payments) {
    this.payments = payments;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumber() {

    return number;
}
...
```

And in Payment:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AccountPK.class)
public class Payment {
@Id
private int id;
private Timestamp date;
private float amount;
private String currency;
private String detail;
@Id
private int accountId;
@Id
private int counterAccountId;
private int labelId;

@ManyToOne
private Account account;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Timestamp getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
    this.date = date;
...
```

How can I join those?

Comment: I think you should have 2 instances in Payment. One for account and another for counterAccount. ManyToOne with both the ids doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I editted my question to contain more code

Comment: Why would you include those two FKs in the ID, since you already have an ID column in Payment which, I presume, uniquely identifies the payment. Just make that your entity ID. Then remove accountId and counterAccountId from the Payment class. You should have 2 ManyToOne associations instead.

Comment: Well it's homework from school so I need to solve it this according to the scheme

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `id` field is *not* part of the primary key, remove its `@Id` annotation. Then annotate the two account fields like this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AccountPK.class)
public class Payment {
private int id;
private Timestamp date;
private float amount;
private String currency;
private String detail;
private int labelId;

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Account account;

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Account counterAccount;
...
```

Some examples like this are in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) section 2.4.1.